# How to send sms and receive the result without SMS_READ or similar permission in Android

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions

I want to send an sms message and know about if it is sent or not without using any sms related permissions.

I have tried using an intent and checking the activity result but that is not consistent and highly dependent on the application handling the sms. Sometimes it works sometimes it does not.

I am able to do this with READ_SMS permission and using a ContentObserver but i would like to know if it is possible without requiring any sms related permission from the user.

My use case will be like this:

- User presses a button in my app
- Default sms application opens with a message body i have prepared
- User edits the message if he/she likes to or not, then sends the sms (or not)

I just want to know if he/she sent the message or not. I don't care if it is received or not. I am already able to do what i want with using a content observer but that requires me to use SMS_READ permission. I would not like to use any SMS related permission if possible.

Comment: You have in mind something like "read" notification, as Facebook messages work ?

Comment: You need to write your own receiver for getting msg delivery report

Comment: @VVB `BroadcastReceiver` works with permissions.

Comment: Yes I know but without that it is just impossible

Comment: I edited the question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, what you want is not generally possible.

`ACTION_SEND`, `ACTION_SENDTO`, `ACTION_VIEW`, etc. are not designed for `startActivityForResult()` in the first place. No app has to return any sort of result for those. Even if an app returns a result, that result does not have to indicate whether the person actually sent the SMS or not, or whether the user sent the SMS to the address you originally requested or not.

There is no requirement for any SMS client to somehow let third parties know about sent SMS messages, other than via the permission-protected APIs that you are using. In fact, offering this information without permissions would be a privacy violation.

If you do not want to hold SMS-related permissions, that's fine, but then you will have to settle for not knowing whether or not the user actually sent the SMS.